Sitecore TDS connection failed,
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Sitecore 10.3, and I'm trying to test the connection with my project, but I'm getting the following error:
Connection Test Failed: Sitecore TDS connection failed. Please check that the Sitecore Web URL and Sitecore Deploy Folder point to the same location. Verify your settings with the settings in IIS.

TDS version: 6.0.4
I have done the following steps:

Double-checked the Sitecore Web URL and Sitecore Deploy Folder path.
I created a new project and tried to make the connection, but I'm getting the same error.
When I installed TDS version 5.8 on my system, I received the following error:


[Please provide the specific error message here.


Did you try deleting _DEV folder on your website root which allowed TDS to install the connector again?

Yes, I had deleted it, but it’s resolved now. I have just updated the TDS version to 6.0.0.13.

Kindly close the question if it has been resolved. Thanks

I’m voting to close this question because this is resolved by user with the updated TDS version.
